# How can I change the decorator function name dynamically to be able to understand cProfile reports?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, cprofile, functools

My problem is the following,

**1** - I created a `functools.wraps` decorator function to log some runtime information.

I choose to use `functools.wraps` because it was supposed to `update a wrapper function to look like the wrapped function`.

So, my decorator look like this:

```
def log_execution(logger):

    def _log_execution(method):

        @functools.wraps(method)
        def _logged_execution(*args, **kwargs):
            logger.log('log some info')
            return method(*args, **kwargs)

        return _logged_execution

    return _log_execution
```

**2** - Then, considering I decorated some of my functions like that:

```
# Create logger
current_logger = create_logger('logger test')


# Function func_a and sub functions
def func_a():
    func_a1()
    func_a2()

@log_execution(current_logger)
def func_a1():
    ...

@log_execution(current_logger)
def func_a2():
    ...


# Function func_b and sub functions
def func_b():
    func_b1()
    func_b2()

@log_execution(current_logger)
def func_b1():
    ...

@log_execution(current_logger)
def func_b2():
    ...
```

**3** - Now if I profile my code and if I take a look at the generated reports, it is really hard to understand which function is called by another, when passing by this decorator.

**For example**: if I take a look at `func_a` call graph, I will have the following:

[image]

**What I would like is**:

[image]

**or**:

[image]

**or**:

[image]

**So my question is:**

How can I change the decorator function name dynamically to be able to better understand my profiling reports?

`functools.wraps` does not seems to do the job here!